# Smart use of ParallelMap over Plus

Tags: parallelization

I'm looking for ways to speed up calculation of a integral with a many-terms integrant. The obvious way is to go in parallel. I was surprised, but for some tests integration by `ParallelMap` over each term wasn't faster than one-core `Integrate` function.

I went further and made a small study. I tested a few methods of integration:

1. Standart `Integrate` without any modification
2. `Integrate` inside one-core `Map`
3. `Integrate` inside `ParallelMap` with different methods of parallelization
4. A "smart" parallelization: first split the sum into subsums, number of them is equal to the number of parallel kernels (4 kernels in my case), and then integrate the subsums in parallel.

The code and the results are:

```
runTest[n_] := With[{terms = Sum[a[i] z^i, {i, n}]},
  With[{newterms = Plus @@@ Partition[List @@ term, n/$KernelCount]},
   {{"Integrate",
      First[AbsoluteTiming[Integrate[terms, {z, 0, z}];]]},
    {"Map",
      First[AbsoluteTiming[Map[Integrate[#, {z, 0, z}] &, terms];]]},
    {"ParallelMap (Automatic)",
      First[AbsoluteTiming[ParallelMap[Integrate[#, {z, 0, z}] &, terms];]]},
    {"ParallelMap (FinestGrained)",
      First[AbsoluteTiming[ParallelMap[Integrate[#, {z, 0, z}] &, terms, Method -> "FinestGrained"];]]},
    {"ParallelMap (CoersestGrained)",
      First[AbsoluteTiming[ParallelMap[Integrate[#, {z, 0, z}] &, terms, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"];]]},
    {"Partition & ParallelMap",
      First[AbsoluteTiming[Plus @@ ParallelMap[Integrate[#, {z, 0, z}] &, newterms];]]}}
   ]]

numOfSamples = 75;
Monitor[test = Table[runTest[n], {n, $KernelCount, numOfSamples $KernelCount, $KernelCount}];, n]

With[{data = Transpose[test[[All, All, 2]]],
      names = test[[1, All, 1]]},
ListPlot[data,DataRange -> {$KernelCount, numOfSamples $KernelCount},
         PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> names, PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
         AxesLabel -> {"Number of terms", "Time, s"}]
]
```

[image]

There are a couple of interesting things on the plot. First, the `Integrate` function knows its job and works fine on one kernel (better than most parallelized versions). Second, all mapped versions has a linear dependence on number of terms (not surprising due to simple integrants). Third, comparison of *Map* and *ParallelMap (FinestGrained)* gives a good expamle of inappropriate parallelization. Fourth, and here I'm surprised, the *ParallelMap (CoersestGrained)* and *Partition & ParallelMap* have a significant difference in speed.
The only explanation I have is that *ParallelMap (CoersestGrained)* still works term-by-term, and *Partition & ParallelMap* uses power of internal algorithms of `Integrate`.

My questions are:

- Is my last guess correct?
- Is the *Partition & ParallelMap* method the most simple and fast? Or one can use `ParallelMap` for this problem in a smarter way (not just changing the method of parallelization)?

Comment: This is a very nice comparison of methods (+1). The reason why `Integrate` is so much better at handling a bunch of terms at a time instead of term by term as determined by some version of `Map` is probably because of the overhead involved in integrating an expression. You incur some overhead each time you call `Integrate` and this adds up. This is how it often is; you want to let Mathematica's built-in functions work as much as possibly by themselves, so I'm not really surprised about only `Integrate` versus `Partition` & `ParallelMap`. `FinestGrained` however is surprising, I think.